How can I group values by label in Prometheus query?
This is my metric data
sync_unit_type {region="krg"} 1731441289.
Value is datetime represented as seconds (Unix time). There are different regions, also values are updated constantly every 5-7 minutes.
In Grafana UI I need to group records by region and take the max value for that specific region, which represents the latest time where some event occurred, also need to represent this as table which will have 2 columns:

Region name
date and time represented as dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss

Currently I am trying to achieve this using this PromQL query, which does not work at all:
max by (region) (sync_unit_type{job="main (prod)", region=~"$Region"} * 1000) (multiplying by 1000 as Grafana expects milliseconds)
I already configured $Region dashboard variable, so I can filter out values by specific region.

What is the actual question here? Query seems fine, grouping is already done.

The query returns nothing.

there should be one row for each region in the final table which contains max value

Query looks fine. Check for typos and such.

The query works now, but it does not return single aggregated max value for each region, instead it returns bunch of values for each region following each other, like 10 rows for region a, then another 10 rows for region b, etc, I need single aggregated value for each region.

Probably you have Type of query set to Time series in Query options. Change it to Instant.

Thanks it seems to be working now. If no metric returned with specific region in the latest prometheus request, can we somehow take the value from the previous available results, because I dont see all regions now.
